# Getter inside setter in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm using this variable

```
public var tick: Int64 {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: TICK) as? Int64 ?? 0
    }
    set(v) {
        let cur = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: TICK) as? Int64 ?? 0 + v
        UserDefaults.standard.set(cur, forKey: TICK)
    }
}
```

But I want to know, that is the proper way to call getter in inside setter? I mean:

```
set(v) {
    let cur = /*HOW TO CALL GETTER HERE? */ + v
    UserDefaults.standard.set(cur, forKey: TICK)
}
```

if I use `self` instead of `/*HOW TO CALL GETTER HERE? */` , it doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply call the value (`tick`) within its setter to get the old value:

```
public var tick: Int64 {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: TICK) as? Int64 ?? 0
    }
    set(v) {
        let cur = tick + v
        UserDefaults.standard.set(cur, forKey: TICK)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A standard implementation of a computed variable with getter and setter is as follows:

```
private var stored: String

public var computed: String {
    get {
        return stored
    }
    set {
        stored = newValue
    }
}
```

The name `newValue` in a setter definition represents the value which is being applied.

You could throw the following into a playground to see:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    private var stored: String = ""

    public var computed: String {
        get {
            return self.stored
        }
        set {
            self.stored = newValue
        }
    }
}

var value = SomeStruct()
print(value.computed)
value.computed = "new string"
print(value.computed)
```

If you really wanted to reference the getter in your setter definition, you could. Perhaps you would want to only apply the `newValue` in the setter based on some kind of condition of the getter:

```
public var computed: String {
    get {
        return self.stored
    }
    set {
        self.stored = self.computed == "" ? self.computed : newValue
    }
}
```

This is also valid and should be able to fit your requirements.

Comment: So, no way to call getter?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from referencing `tick` in your setter definition. @Vyacheslav

Comment: I wanna call getter. Because of it might contains more complicated logic